# Make an random shaped image rectangular ( photoshop )

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, selections, transform

I have a shirt imagine, that was originally rectangular, but is now deformed:

[image]

I want to make my selection " fille the rectangle ", i dont mean to just "zoom into it ", but more like transform it like a vector shape. It would also be convenient if i could vectorise my image in the first place in the process.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

To get your image back into a "rectangle" shape, you could use *Lens Correction* (**Filter → Lens Correction or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and play with the settings there

Go to **Custom** and use the *Geometric Distortion*, *Perspective* and *Scale* adjustments.

Then use the *Clone Stamp Tool* (<kbd>S</kbd>) to fill in your edges.

---

As far as turning your image into vector goes, **you can't***.

If you have the image of the dog, you can just recreate the (very simple) design in Photoshop or Illustrator.

<sub>*You can try methods such as auto-trace (in Illustrator) but that won't produce the optimal results. The image you are working with is a raster image (the photo) of a raster image (the dog on the shirt) - which makes this very difficult to turn into vector.</sub>